# Allowing ampersand (&) in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I googled for this but without luck.

I have a textarea in a form that I'm trying to send via ajax with jQuery. My problem is when the textarea contains ampersand (&) it breaks. That is any text contained after `&` will not be fetched including the ampersand (&). I am sending the data as follows:

```
message = "What are the concerns you are looking to address? "+othr+".\n";
var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&company=' + company + '&message=' + message + '&othr=' + othr + '&vpb_captcha_code=' + vpb_captcha_code + '&submitted=1';
$.ajax({  

type: "POST",  

url: "contactus-contact-form.php",  

data: dataString ,
```

I read `encodeURIComponent()` and tried implementing the same but it does not work. Any pointers?

EDIT:The following fails to obtain the text values:

```
message = "What are the concerns or security issues you are looking to address? "+othr+".\n";
var data0 = {name: + name + email: + email + company: + company + message: + message + 
othr: + othr + vpb_captcha_code: + vpb_captcha_code + submitted: "1"};

$.ajax({  

type: "POST",  
url: "contactus-contact-form.php",  
data: data0,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: You can simply replace all `&` with `&amp;` before processing it. Otherwise use `serialize()`, or a data object with named properties, instead of concatenating strings (which is error prone anyway).

Comment: Why are you sending the data as a string? You can send it as an object, jQuery will handle everything.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie how do i replace it? The textarea is part of a form the users use to send their query.

Comment: @MMM please see the edit above

Comment: @Sarah: That's invalid Javascript, you want to do `{name: name, email: email}`..

Answer (score 5):

`&` is the character used to separate key/value pairs in form encoded data. You need to escape it if you want to use as part of the data.

The easiest way to do that is to let jQuery take care of building the form encoded string for you. Pass an object to the `data` argument:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    data: {
        name: name, 
        email: email, 
        company: company, 
        message: message, 
        othr: othr,
        vpb_captcha_code: vpb_captcha_code,
        submitted: 1
    },
    // etc
```

If you really want to do it manually, then the `encodeURIComponent` function will work:

```
var dataString = "name=" + encodeURIComponent(name) + "&email=" + encodeURIComponent(email) // etc etc etc
```

Answer (score 0):

i met this problem,
for a specific reason I needed to display &amp; instead of & in a textarea.
To do so, i replaced "&" by "&amp;amp;"

I hope it's help

Answer (score -2):

ou can resolve your problem using encodeURIComponent() function .You have just change the code as below.I think you have set the textarea value to  variable othr.You can just encode this variable only using encodeURIComponent(othr).That mean You can parse the textarea value using encodeURIComponent method.

```
 message = "What are the concerns you are looking to address? "+othr+".\n";
var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&company=' + company + '&message=' + message + '&othr=' + encodeURIComponent(othr) + '&vpb_captcha_code=' + vpb_captcha_code + '&submitted=1';
$.ajax({  

type: "POST",  

url: "contactus-contact-form.php",  

data: dataString ,
});
```

or

---

```
message = "What are the concerns or security issues you are looking to address? "+othr+".\n";
var data0 = {name: + name + email: + email + company: + company + message: + message + 
othr: +encodeURIComponent(othr) + vpb_captcha_code: + vpb_captcha_code + submitted: "1"};

$.ajax({  

type: "POST",  
url: "contactus-contact-form.php",  
data: data0,   
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: Please specify the problem occured

Comment: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`? — Don't do that. `data0` isn't JSON. And if you *do* pass an object to `data` (which you *should*) then jQuery will take care of escaping it for you, so you must not use `encodeURIComponent` as well.

Comment: You are suggesting invalid JavaScript, you are constructing the object all wrong...